# How to remove unwanted colors in picture?

Tags: lightroom, photoshop, photo-editing, artifacts, chromatic-aberration

I took product photos for my company and am currently editing them. However, some of the white parts of the shirt look a little odd zoomed out. When I zoom in, I see the following:
 [image]

I'd like to remove the red artifacts that appear on the text. Any advice on how to do that in Photoshop or Lightroom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Lightroom there is an option to tick labeled 'Remove chromatic abberation' or words to that effect. Tick that and, hey presto!